# Как изменить ширину textarea и поставить на место кнопку?

Tags: jquery, css, javascript

На [этой странице](http://ask-carol.com/ask-question/) есть форма, в которой находиться textarea, в котором iframe.

Мне очень нужно сделать ширину textarea 80% и fontsize 125%. И у кнопки Submit внизу сделать верхний и нижний отступ по 25 пикселей.

Но у меня не получается.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос слишком размыт, вряд ли у кого будет желание лезть и препарировать какой-то там код для расплывчатого вопроса.

Ширина - `width: 80%;`: зависит от предков.
Размер шрифта - `font-size: 125%;`: лучше использовать `em`.
Отступы - `margin: 25px 0;`: No comments.

Comment: @TheDoctor я это отлично знаю, но правила CSS не действуют на textarea. Почему? Не знаю!

Comment: @eprivalov1, тьфу, я не туда смотрел.  
В коде какая-то адова хрень творится, если честно.  
В `div` идёт сначала `iframe` и только после него идёт `textarea`. Они не вложены, более того - `textarea` вообще с `display: none;`.  
Структура кода очень сомнительная, надо поправить, а потом уже стили рисовать.